# run maven from eclipse as root

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-docker-plugin

Maven builds for docker plugin (`mvn package docker:build`) fail because docker must be executed as root (something about opening a socket on port 80).

Is there a way I can sudo a maven build launched from eclipse `Run As..`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the answer to the eclipse run as sudo question, but a solution to the docker build from maven plugin problem that works for me:

Run docker host on the dev machine on a tcp socket (restricted to localhost) instead of a unix socket (you can configure the env var DOCKER_HOST as tcp://localhost:2375 on the eclipse run configuration). That way you don't need to be root to do the docker build.